# rails MapLayers javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

im just starting to use RoR and i seem to miss an important point. i tried to recreate the example application on the mapLayers git repo
https://github.com/pka/map_layers/wiki 
all i get is the javascript code generated by rails as text. when i copy that code into my index.html.erb i get the expected result. 
what am i forgeting

thanks in advance
jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3? Or Rails > 2.3.5?  If so, this library is conflicting with Rails XSS protection (http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).  You probably want to fiddle with the 'raw' helper to make your javascript render as javascript.

Comment: yeah im using Rails 3
and the raw helper did the trick...thanks a lot